# IoCResolveException in release mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm working in a Xamarin app with MVVMCross.

The app works perfectly when I run in debug mode.

But if try to run in release mode it fails with the exception:

```
Exception masked MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve type 
FlexConta.Contracts.Service.IUserService
[mvx]     at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type t) [0x00035] in <0da3cbd163cf47a29ec04fff5bb9eecd>:0 
[mvx]   at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve[T] () [0x00000] in <0da3cbd163cf47a29ec04fff5bb9eecd>:0 
[mvx]   at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.Resolve[TService] () [0x00005] in <0da3cbd163cf47a29ec04fff5bb9eecd>:0 
[mvx]   at FlexConta.Core.AppStart.Start (System.Object hint) [0x00000] in <880d0bdc2a5448ffb4d7b35d827753b5>:0 
[mvx]   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.MvxSplashScreenAppCompatActivity.TriggerFirstNavigate () [0x00005] in <74631770bbbe4bff8d50c85acb55083c>:0 
[mvx]   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.MvxSplashScreenAppCompatActivity.InitializationComplete () [0x00009] in <74631770bbbe4bff8d50c85acb55083c>:0 
[mvx]   at MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.<InitializeFromSplashScreen>b__7_1 () [0x0000a] in <099dd6f64bd74189922e6888bc76e146>:0 
[mvx]   at MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxMainThreadDispatcher.ExceptionMaskedAction (System.Action action) [0x00000] in <0da3cbd163cf47a29ec04fff5bb9eecd>:0
```

I'm using the MVVMCross IOC container and I'm registering de dependencies as follows:

```
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Repository")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserRestAPI>(new UserRestAPI());

        RegisterAppStart(new AppStart());
    }
```

The User service class:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IDocumentTypesRepository _documentTypesRepository;
    private readonly IUserRestAPI _userRestAPI;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository, IDocumentTypesRepository documentTypesRepository, IUserRestAPI userRestAPI)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _documentTypesRepository = documentTypesRepository;
        _userRestAPI = userRestAPI;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

What may be happening?

Comment: If your Linker setting to set to something other than `None` for your Release  build, add a Linker `[Preserve (AllMembers = true)] on your `UserService` class, Actually all your `*Service` and `*Repository` classes....

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `PreserveAttribute` in your PCL and add it to the classes that the linker is stripping out. [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#Preserving_Code) describe the use as

> If you do not want to take a dependency on the Xamarin libraries – for
>   example, you are building a cross platform portable class library
>   (PCL) – you can still use the Android.Runtime.Preserve attribute. To
>   do this, declare a PreserveAttribute class within the Android.Runtime
>   namespace like this:

```
namespace Android.Runtime
{
    public sealed class PreserveAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public bool AllMembers;
        public bool Conditional;
    }
}
```

If you want to prevent linking of your shared PCL you can use [link skip](http://If%20you%20want%20to%20prevent%20linking%20of%20your%20shared%20PCL%20you%20can%20use%20[link%20skip](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip)%20to%20prevent%20the%20linker%20from%20stripping%20away%20code%20from%20you%20PCL.%20In%20your%20android%20cs%20proj%20just%20add%20%60%3CAndroidLinkSkip%3EYourPCLAssemblyNameHerer%3C/AndroidLinkSkip%3E%60%20or%20via%20the%20properties%20UI) to prevent the linker from stripping away code from you PCL.

In your android cs proj just add `<AndroidLinkSkip>YourPCLAssemblyNameHerer</AndroidLinkSkip>` or via the properties UI. Android Options -> Linker -> Skip linking assemblies, enter your PCL assembly name in the input.